# How can I optimize this SQL query without changing its logic?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I am developing a chatting application. I have written a SQL to get the active chats associated with the user. It used to get user to user chat and group chats based on sort it in descending order based on when the last message was sent. I'm trying to optimize this query. I'm using MySQL.

`group_attributes`  table schema :

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Chat_Group_id | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| IsGroup       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description   | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

UpdatedAt column is updated with current timestamp when a message record is added in `chat_group_messages` table.

`chat_groups` table schema:

```
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Chat_Group_id | int        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt     | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt     | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| admin         | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`chat_group_messages` table:

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Chat_Group_id | int           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message       | varchar(5000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt     | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt     | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have yet to add forign keys in above schemas as I've yet tofully understand how associations work in sequalize module.

**query 1 **:
This is used to find user to user chats associated with logged in user.
It selects user groups from `group_attributes` table and joins them with `chat_groups` table on column `chat_group_id`  and `users` table on column `user_id` and then, filters them with :

1. checks if user exists in the group and where at least 1 message of that group exists in the table `chat_group_messages`
2. isGroup flag is false
3. `user_id` is not equal to the requesting user (logged in user)
4. whether logged in user is in a group with another user

point 1 is needed because of the way my frontend works it creates arbitrary groups between users upon execution of certain actions ( I will change the this behavior in future to remove this filter )

point 2 gives checks if it is a Group

point 3 and 4 are needed to filter out records of logged in user while checking if they exist in a group

**query 2**:
This is used to find group chats associated with logged in user.

This selects from `group_attributes` table and performs inner join on `chat_groups` table on column `chat_group_id` and weather `user_id` is equal to logged user id. This query filters it out on basis of weather `IsGroup` flag is true i.e. the association is a group containing 2 or more users.

At the end the union of 2 queries is taken to it is ordered by descending on column `UpdatedAt` to  get columns which were last updated i.e. groups where messages were last sent.

```
select *  from (
      select 
      ca.chat_group_id , ca.isgroup , 
      u.user_id ,  u.username , 
      name group_name , description as  group_description , 
      ca.updatedat
      from group_attributes ca
      inner join chat_groups cg on ca.chat_group_id = cg.chat_group_id
      inner join users u on cg.user_id = u.user_id  
      where 
      exists ( select user_id from chat_group_messages cgm where  cgm.chat_group_id = ca.chat_group_id )
      and isgroup =  false and u.user_id != ${logged_user.id} 
      and ${logged_user.id} in (
        select  cg2.user_id  from chat_groups cg2 
        where cg.Chat_Group_id = cg2.Chat_Group_id
            )
    
    union 
    
    select 
       ca.chat_group_id , ca.isgroup , 
        null as user_id , null as username , 
        ca.name as group_name , ca.description as group_description , 
        ca.updatedat 
        from group_attributes ca
        inner join chat_groups cg on cg.chat_group_id = ca.chat_group_id and cg.user_id = ${logged_user.id}
        where isgroup = true 
        ) as temp 
        order by updatedat desc ;
```

group_attributes table is supposed to be small whereas other 2 table are supposed to be comparatively huge.

this query runs quickly in my development database. But I think in production it will take a long while and will probably lock the tables for a while, slowing down the whole application.

I don't know how to optimize this query without breaking this logic.

Explain query shows this:

```
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type       | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY           | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |    8 |      100 | Using filesort                             |
|  2 | DERIVED           | cg2        | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |   66 |       10 | Using where; Start temporary               |
|  2 | DERIVED           | ca         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | webapp.cg2.Chat_Group_id |    1 |       10 | Using where                                |
|  2 | DERIVED           | cgm        | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |   16 |       10 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
|  2 | DERIVED           | cg         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |   66 |       10 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
|  2 | DERIVED           | u          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | webapp.cg.user_id        |    1 |      100 | End temporary                              |
|  5 | UNCACHEABLE UNION | cg         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |   66 |       10 | Using where                                |
|  5 | UNCACHEABLE UNION | ca         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | webapp.cg.Chat_Group_id  |    1 |       10 | Using where                                |
|  6 | UNION RESULT      | <union2,5> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary                            |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Show us explain/execution plan output.

Comment: Can you do UNION ALL instead of UNION? Is a UNION really needed?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. I've added The explain output

Comment: I could use UNION ALL  but i would require a disctict oprator at chat_group_id because my first query leaves some duplicate rows. This I think would be same as using just UNION.

Comment: You can perhaps skip the UNION. Instead LEFT JOIN users. OR the conditions.

Comment: query 1 is used to filter user-to-user chats and query 2 is used to filter group-chats. I'm not sure what you mean by skip UNION and left JOIN users

Comment: Your design seems a bit strange, to me. Why have you got an IsGroup field in your group_attributes table? Why would a table holding group attributes have records that weren't groups and what are these records, if not groups? You are also saying the updatedAt field in this table is changed when records are inserted in another table - this makes no sense, surely you would update this field only when this record is updated?

Comment: I'm new at database design.   Essentially all chats are associated with groups. Weather they be 1-to-1 user chats or 1-to-many group chats. 1-to-1 user chats are identified by isGroup flag being false. main difference between them and groups is, group members are fixed at 2 and no other 1-1 chat can exist between 2 users where IsGroup flag is false.

Comment: I should have probably named the table association_attributes. As for the UpdatedAt column, I didn't want to add another column or table that showed when the last msg was sent in that group. So I reused UpdatedAt column provided by sequalize ORM for this purpose. If you have any suggestions regarding design please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables would make a bit more sense if `group_attributes` is renamed to `chat_groups` and current `chat_groups` renamed to `chat_group_users`.

Drop the unnecessary AI PK on `chat_groups` in favour of PK (Chat_Group_id, user_id) and secondary index on (user_id, Chat_Group_id).

Also, avoid the confusing mix of capitalisation and underscores. Choose a convention and stick to it. All lowercase with underscores is most portable but whatever you choose, be consistent.

As well as changing the structure of chat_groups, you need an index on chat_group_messages (Chat_Group_id).

This should give the same result:

```
SELECT
    ga.Chat_Group_id, ga.IsGroup,
    ga.name as group_name, ga.description as group_description, ga.updatedAt,
    u.user_id ,  u.username
FROM group_attributes ga
LEFT JOIN chat_groups cg
    ON ga.IsGroup = 0
    AND ga.Chat_Group_id = cg.Chat_Group_id
    AND cg.user_id <> ${logged_user.id}
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON cg.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM chat_groups
    WHERE Chat_Group_id = ga.Chat_Group_id AND user_id = ${logged_user.id}
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM chat_group_messages
    WHERE Chat_Group_id = ga.Chat_Group_id
)
ORDER BY ga.updatedAt DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please qualify each column name; it is hard to track what comes from what table.

Based on user1191247's reformulation, I recommend adding these composite indexes:

```
ga:  INDEX(IsGroup,  Chat_Group_id, description, updatedAt)
ga:  INDEX(Chat_Group_id)
u:   INDEX(user_id,  username)
cg:  INDEX(Chat_Group_id,  user_id)
chat_group_messages:  INDEX(Chat_Group_id)
```